# trim whitespaces in unicode string

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, trim

**Hi all!** I have in my database's table records with fields of VARCHAR(100) of charset utf-8 general-ci.
When I echo it to the web page, it echos string and many-many some square symbols. 
How can I delete them and leave inly word. Wthas the problem. Will be a problem with searching? Thanx!

Comment: A better question would be why those "square symbols" are there...

Comment: You could start by showing the output of `echo bin2hex($string); echo $string;` and the result you were expecting. That could give some clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the script encoded in UTF-8 and do you also UTF8 for the connection to the database?
You can set the charset of the connection using the following query directly after connecting

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8'
```

Comment: <?php
$link    = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($link);

echo "The current character set is: $charset\n";
?>                                                              The current character set is: latin1

Comment: The table and connection character sets are two separate things. As Dr.Molle says, execute the above query as soon as you connect.

Comment: Use `mysql_set_charset` in prefernce to `SET NAMES`, in order to keep `mysql_real_escape_string` aware of the correct charset.

Answer (score 2):

You are a PHP nerd and just started to work with PHP and mysql. In order to work unicode data you need to know  something before proceeding.

First make sure your table fields are set to use “utf8_general_ci” collation to accept all languages character sets. Of course you can use any other collation starting with “utf8_” for example if your database needs only English and Persian characters you can choose “utf8_persian_ci”.

Second: When writing some PHP code working with MYSQL you need to explicitly ask PHP to transfer your uni-code data in utf8 format so it will match the destination data type which is utf8.  This will cause the client`s data to be stored “as-is” in MYSQL.

If you don`t follow this rule MYSQL will store your utf8 data as question marks.

In order to avoid this to happen you only need to write the following line before any query in your PHP code.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

So, first we need to connect to the database.
Second, call

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

Third, do other operations.

Answer (score 0):

I would try utf8_decode($string);

Comment: ��������� ����� ����� ����������

Comment: Collation = utf8_general_ci.     type = varchar(100). English words echoes good, russian - bad. Whats the reason...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the character encoding on your webpage

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```